# http response missing content length

Tags: javascript, http-headers, httpclient

I'm new in web services. I have the following issue.

If I make the following GET I don't receive the `content-length` in the response. I receive the result, but I need to know the `content-length` in the response.

```
GET /api/xxxxxxxx/hourly/q/pws:ICATALUN7.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.wunderground.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

But using the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch` in the header, I receive the `content-length`. The only problem is that I receive the following format in the response result.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-CreationTime: 0.116
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Mar 2015 15:35:33 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 2446
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Tue, 10 Mar 2015 15:35:34 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2015 15:35:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: DT=1426001733:24382:365-d10; path=/; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT; domain=.wunderground.com

�      ���n�6 ���)_g1I�sWd���!���b�%O��fE�}:ح̓D��D&:Ԓ)K.�4ɟ�����h��:��`|3*�_�$
�h|3�p|U�ʂd��O_��%��ǋ,[�L&���z��� �'q���,^M��4[�d�'��<�z����G=��n�S�϶�7��5߂�֏ˋ������n��S��i��������?�����ϻ��'\T%��c
茯ʍ�������U��^?n�_�}i0ۿ|
��g! ��t\iT/>�wM�~M��b�]~d�ϟ��'��Ë)ϰ+`��F���W+���٢,g" ��N�,+��n }��~���(?�l1��j���Y�.
VW�-��*�]a~�ý��o�๸��!�� -.����(�/���G��X�_����D�i4o:Y�穦����_~����e�w�^�u������V~���*��,X���fD�e���ܶ9��WA���} �qU���8�2� �9>`_~G~���=s�,n�r8�v͎w=�7��G�ؓ^o�m��CNf��Iy��<|��z�e��/� ������fT��t��W�b���]����l���˗���̓�|<���ܗ�V��D�ku��Kxp��*̿yu���K   #��K�z~�������U�j���|ky�S,�e�pW���'�,�ǅ��l�[���x�{���U�$n9\#�,��q���z�\
u����.F��K���kE�n:G=� �:�b!lAj�P�
se��U�*S�Q��T�������Ե����=fu��٨��G^�,6v�C�;���/���v$ÎY�
c� ��b�[w��ˋ���k�~�Ҵ�Z`���Y��%�#�C^{��~�2�We� �:�,u��Q��R�i�ZQg���0u��<��u�lֱ�w`����V�!�uHU��G& ��n_Rkǩ�y����%�N�aG`g�7��zU�Π`g(����M@ȍ�ص��h���#v5]vݱ{�bYի0v����o�[)��C���\|p�B��u�bݮ�)�{��^��%������?� a�a� c̒i�)�y��Cf���`U���Q:��`w����0�����u��^�xX���A<x�f�0.��6   �Y�*VP���N�<��n��F^'�L�9���<�xV�<��cU����)�hQs�G�����   ���/x����牃G�CW��x<���m�3)♪�g"|������i��S�3���Ս<.���P�!p�gQȳ�%��/,^�,M^/��wD�݁<[�w
n�l
y���Y ��yɳ5y���ץ+O���7HeU0ت(���؅�K���{��!�<�OQ���l�:ҍ=I��(����I���1\^�\-_/���F�<M*#���z,��|k������T��F�l=o�ZQ͝|��Y3�!�TeI1ģE�`HYF���(�6��7<^=�a?a�<˩H��Y��M�E,
��.�1�,�'�obY#rE��@J�T6p�6��
�=�h;-��Os��@d�)dѨ���x^�A'��Q����U�2����lTG��(-j�D���2ʪ��[��R-����Az(߲����,�!%�*��@|ؤ��%V1`F��f�<_k��l�?���׵�QM�gO��$�E5!W\6)�A��cU��=����
�p,b�*n�4|���$Ը��|��4��G�f�G�g��͆fֱ��Ő�
q\|���ŧ|��s����̓��7��k�ȓ�W.�z&_a���@H   �ʆ��1x�34y�4�zK�q�|B�Ƀ��@�cϔn�C�V��x��l�k��&�x�����!
G^M�w
5�;��;���%۲�z=<��TYq�����zV\V���5xm�1$����n��Y
�)�W��1��J�+*�G��'�e�j�Z���h���\�w�6x����`�w��[��n��<�/ZJd�p    r��#r����|5w���o����=r�kF5R�+��ҍԲ�w`�D�-�J�+HDNpz�\Vd�&�-y���R��LR!���UM���ի2yR��&��NO�ˊ����&x�fy�u��JeB��=�z�����<���
�G�g��eF�j�Z���o7��ߜ�^գ����(�t�sYի2zR��E�����/t FO��6+�z�~sJj�Ώ�Co�<��b:0�� ^k�3��a
�7���b��'
�h��ذū=��֦��p�dm������'�m�}���W�U��J�+�8�
```

How could I receive the `content-length` and the result in the right format using javascript?

Comment: `Content-Length: 2446` is right there in the response.  What's the issue?

Comment: The response format. If I put the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch` in the header, I receive the content length. But how could I decode the response in the right JSON format format? If I remove from the header the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch` I receive the response in JSON but no the `content length`.

Comment: You told the system that you accept gzip, and it gave you gzip.  The JSON is there, it's just compressed.  I also suspect that in lieu if a content length, it's sending the data with chunked encoding.  In any case, your HTTP client shouldn't require a content length header.  HTTP 1.0 servers won't always send it, and poorly behaved HTTP 1.1 servers won't either.  Why are you writing your own HTTP client anyway?  This should be all abstracted.  Are you running JavaScript client-side, or in Node.js or similar?

Comment: I'm running a javascript server side scripting. It's similar than Node.js. Yes, it's sending the data in chunked encoding. But, Is there some way to descompress gzip in javascript?

Comment: You'll want to use a native library for this for speed if you can.  In Node.js, there's:  https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html  What platform are you using?

Comment: I'm using a proprietary software. I tried it with node.js and it works fine. Thanks Brad for your time and your support!